# Identity usermanager cannot find the Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a user to a role after successfully creating the user.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);
    var user = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = model.PhoneNumber,
        PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
        NationalId = model.NationalId,
        FullName = model.FullName
    };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.NationalId);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var res = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
        _logger.LogInformation(3, "Applicant created a new account with password.");
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    AddErrors(result);

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

But, I get this error.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Role ADMIN does not exist.

**Update:**
I called the

```
var myrole = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin");
```

and it returned null. but when i inspect

```
var roles = _roleManager.Roles
```

i get all the roles including "Admin"

Comment: Did you "create" the `IdentityRole` before adding a user to it?

Comment: sure, the role is created in the seed method and i verified it exists in the database

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in the seed method. i do not understand it however.

in the seed method i used the RoleStore to add roles.

```
 var roles = new[] {"Admin", "Applicant", "Student", "Role1", "Role2", "Role3", "Role4"};
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);

            if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
                await roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
        }
```

the roles where created successfully in the database table AspNetRoles.

but when acted upon, the roles were never found.

i replaced the RoleStore with RoleManager

```
 await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
```

and like magic, it all worked out. i will do further research on the difference and the cause to understand it more.